# Why IdeaVim-EasyMotion plugin for pycharm selects the text between cursors instead of moving the cursor

Tags: vim, pycharm

I am using the IdeaVim-EasyMotion (https://github.com/AlexPl292/IdeaVim-EasyMotion) plugin for pycharm. When I use it, it selects texts instead of moving the cursor. Anybody knows how to make it work properly. Cheers!
e.g.,
[It highlights the texts instead of moving the cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKLcf.png)

Comment: Do you hold `shift` while typing the label?

Comment: Yes, I hold `shift` while typing the label, because the label is in uppercase characters.

Comment: I voted to close this question as it is about how to use an uncommon plugin on an IDE. You might have more help asking SuperUser, or opening an issue on the plugin in GitHub.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this same issue and it's super annoying, but I find that even though easymotion presents me with capital letters to select where to jump, lowercase letters work just fine.

So, while this sequence selects text:
`\\foHU`

this does not, but goes to the same place:
`\\fohu`